# jQuery validate throwing a settings error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have jquery validate being called in my `.html` `head` I have a form on page 1 and the same form again on page 2. However if I start on page 1 then go to page 2. When the fields try to validate I get a settings error, and vice versa from page 2 to page 1. After research, it seems the issue is steming from

```
// constructor for validator
$.validator = function( options, form ) {
//  console.log('validator construct');
    this.settings = $.extend( true, {}, $.validator.defaults, options );
//  console.log(this.settings);
    this.currentForm = form;
    this.init();
};
```

If I allow either of those 2 `console.logs`, then no error will display. However if I do not and throw a console.log after `this.init();` then the error will still display.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined
>   jquery.validate.js:894

I'm guessing it needs a few milliseconds to finish setting the variables before the `init()` runs? Is there a better way to prevent this from erring without doing a `console.log()`?. Not all browsers support `console.log` so I don't want there to be an error and cause the script not to finish executing.

- jQuery 1.8.2
- jQuery Validate 1.11.0pre
- jQuery Mobile 1.2

Comment: What is the version of your jQuery.validate?